# How to check all running process (only utilizing memory )in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, apt, dpkg, system

I'd like check all running process in my pc so that I can kill to save my `RAM`
space or uninstall ?
I'd like see unused process just consuming memory (except system process)

Comment: have you tried `sudo ps aux`?

Comment: Have you looked at "System Monitor" tool?

Comment: I got it!! `sudo ps aux` works for me

Answer (score 1):

For me 'top' or even 'htop' is better console tools to check processes

Answer (score 0):

top command gives you the running processes.
Press shift+o then n. This way top sorts the processes by memory consumption.